# When i edit one instance's variable values the others another instance's change too

Tags: c#, class, variables, linked-list

I have two classes, 'Unit' and 'Tile'. both of these have a 'Location' class in them like so...

```
class Unit
{
    // add the stats like name , health, speed and strength.
    public Stats stats = new Stats();

    // add the location coordinates
    public Location location = new Location();
}

public class Tile
{
    // add the stats like name , health, speed and strength.
    public Stats stats = new Stats();

    // represents the ability to move out of tile via either {north,east,south,west};
    public List<bool> movementDirections = new List<bool>() { true, true, true, true };

    // represents the Coorinates to access the tile.
    public Location location = new Location();
}
```

ok so... you'll notice i also have the 'Stats' class on both. both 'Unit' and 'Tile' are new instances and both have new instances of 'Stats' and 'Location' on them.

My issue is that i have got a small piece of code that changes the location of the unit and it's acting strangely.

```
        static void move(Tile tile,int[] coordsChange,Unit unit)
    {
        // Unit player is defined earlier in the script as a new Unit().
        player.stats.name = "Hendry";// just to check. this doesn't change the tile name
        player.location.x = player.location.x + coordsChange[0]; // these both change the tile location also.
        player.location.y = player.location.y + coordsChange[1];
    }
```

since everything is a new instance and the changing of player stats isn't changing the Tile stats i have no idea why but the location change for the player. I have also tested visa versa and the same happens ... it's as though the location classes were linked but the stats classes are not despite no difference in them.

here are those classes BTW.

```
public class Location
{
    private int _x = 0;
    private int _y = 0;

    public int x
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value;}
    }

    public int y
    {
        get { return _y;}
        set { _y = value; }
    }
}

public class Stats
{
    public string name = "default";
    public string className = "default";
    public int health = 10;
    public int strength = 5;
    public int defence = 5;
    public int speed = 5;
    public int intelligence = 5;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks
     zorilya

Comment: What is the player variable?

Comment: You haven't provided an example that replicates your problem.  Somehow, somewhere, you're assigning a reference to the same object to both fields, or you're not properly observing the behavior that you think you are.  Either way, there isn't enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: _"when i edit one instance's variable values the others another instance's change too"_ - then it must be the same entity.

Comment: @HenkHolterman He could be editing both entities.  The code he showed doesn't, but code he didn't show could.  He could also be improperly observing/printing the results such that they appear the same (say, due to improperly closing over a variable) even though they're actually different.  Regardless, without enough code to replicate the problem there's no sense in guessing.

Comment: i'm not printing the result, i'm using the visual studio debug and stepping through, watching them both change at the same instant from the code i showed you... they are not the same instance as you can see they are instantiated with the new keyword

Comment: the player variable (as commented) is a variable set at the begining of the progam. it is static and public

Comment: @Servy I think that if the OP wrote some duplicating setters he wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @zorilya They're separate instances when constructed; that doesn't mean that they're separate instances when your program reaches the method in question.  You could be doing anything in the intervening code, including changing the references to be equal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The importance of encapsulation:

```
class Unit
{
    // add the stats like name , health, speed and strength.
    public Stats stats { get; private set; }
    // add the location coordinates
    public Location location { get; private set; }

    public Unit()
    {
        location = new Location();
        stats = new Stats();
    }

}
```

Same for `Tile`.

**Update**

My theory is that before the call of `move` you have code assigning:

```
player.location = tile.location;
```

or

```
tile.location = player.location;
```

Making `location` a property with private setter, will cause a compiler error for such code.

**Update**

```
public class Location
{
    ...
    your code
    ...

    public void Assign(Location aSource)
    {
        x = aSource.x;
        y = aSource.y;
    }
}

tile.location.Assign(player.location);
```

Comment: This is likely a good idea, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Servy - actually, my crystal ball tells me that `player` and `tile` have the same `Location` reference, and the suggested code change will point it out at compile-time.

Comment: could you please explain what this code change effects?

Comment: I traced it back and found it... I had inadvertantly set the tile location to the player location by referencing the player location and passing it into a method which took the location and assigned it to the Tile... how do i assign just the value not the reference